# (Simple?) inequality in finite dimensional linear spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$, and $V_i\subset V$.

The operator $A : V  \to V $ is symmetric positive definite with respect to the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$.

On these spaces there are two operators, $Q_i: V  \to V_i$, $A_i: V_i \to V_i$, where
\begin{align*}
(A_i v,w) &= (A v, w)~~~\forall w\in V_i
\\
(Q_i v,w) &= (  v, w)~~~\forall w\in V_i.
\end{align*}

Is it possible  to prove the inequality
$$
(Q_iu,Q_iu)\le \lambda (A_i^{-1}Q_iu,u),
$$
for any $u\in V$, where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$?

I am not sure how to introduce $\lambda$ into the inequality.  I tried
$$
(Q_iu,Q_iu) = (A_i A_i^{-1} Q_iu,Q_iu)= (A  A_i^{-1} Q_iu,Q_iu).
$$
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality doesn't seem to help, or at least I don't see how it is applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the first assumption the operator $A_i$ is positive definite. By the second assumption we have  $u-Q_iu\perp V_i$ for any $u\in V.$ Therefore $$\langle A_i^{-1}Q_iu,u\rangle =\langle A_i^{-1}Q_iu,Q_iu\rangle+\langle A_i^{-1}Q_iu,u-Q_iu\rangle\\ =\langle A_i^{-1}Q_iu,Q_iu\rangle \ge \mu_i \langle Q_iu,Q_iu\rangle $$ where $\mu_i$ is the least eigenvalue of $A_i^{-1}.$ Hence $\mu_i=\lambda_i^{-1},$ where $\lambda_i$ is the largest  eigenvalue of $A_i.$ However the largest eigenvalue of $A_i$ is less than or equal to the largest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A.$ Indeed for $v\in V_i$ we have $$\langle A_iv,v\rangle =\langle Av,v\rangle\le \lambda\|v\|^2$$ Summarizing we have obtained $$\langle A_i^{-1}Q_iu,u\rangle\ge \lambda_i^{-1}\langle Q_iu,Q_iu\rangle \ge \lambda^{-1}\langle Q_iu,Q_iu\rangle$$

Comment: Much appreciated. I did not realize $Q$ is a orthogonal projection